# Routing not working consistently for ASP.NET Area pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a situation where I have several controllers in an administration "Area" in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application.

One of the controllers is working fine, the second controller is routing to the default route at the root of the site.

**My default route:**

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Reports", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**My area route:**

```
 public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Administration_default",
            "Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**My working area controller:**

```
 public class ResourcesController : Controller
{
    // GET: Administration/Resources
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var db = new SDRContext())
        {
            var resource = db.Resources.ToList();
            return View(resource);
        }
    }
}
```

**My non-working area controller:**

```
 public class DisplayFieldsController : Controller
{
    private SDRContext db = new SDRContext();

    // GET: Administration/DisplayFields
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var results = db.DisplayFields.ToList();
        return View(results);
    }
}
```

Why when I call the second controller does it default to the root route instead of the administration route I have setup?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your DisplayFields controller exists in the same area folder as the first one. How are you invoking your second controller? Are you doing this from a link? I'm assuming your area is called Administration:

```
Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Index", "DisplayFields", new { Area = 
"Adminstration" },null);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why when I call the second controller does it default to the root route instead of the administration route I have setup?

No. Routes are utilized **in the order they are registered**, period. I suspect if you are having problems that you have not setup your routing in the correct order in application startup. The correct order is to register your area routes *before* your default route.

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
// ...
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

If using attribute routing, you should register it *before* your area routes.